# How do I search a list of dictionaries with multiple keys?

Tags: python

Imagine I have the following list of dictionaries in Python:

```py
[
    {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 20},
    {"name": "Anna", "surname": "Smith", "age": 20},
    {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 22},
]
```

So now I want for example all dictionaries, where `'name'=='John'` and `'surname'=='Doe'`; In this case, the output would be

```
[
    {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 20},
    {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 22},
]
```

I found plenty of examples on how to search a list of dictionary with 1 key but not for 2 or potentially 3 and more keys..

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't call a `list`, which is a built-in python type, such as "list".

Then:

```
lst = [{'name':'John', 'surname':'Doe','age':20},{'name':'Anna','surname':'Smith','age':20},{'name':'John','surname':'Doe','age':22}]


print([d for d in lst if d['name'] == 'John' and d['surname'] == 'Doe'])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe', 'age': 22}]
```

Comment: That  was quick - and so simple, thank you so much; And of course I should not name it list, that was a mistake from typing up the quesiton